# Is Spring Security safe or vulnerable against LDAP Injection?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

Authenticating to the LDAP by Using the JNDI

Can the ldap injection can be done using these parameters

Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL="user1"

Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS="password"